Why my Photoshop brushes don't have sharp ends？
This is the actual situation:

This is the effect I want:


Ae you using a drawing tablet? Do you have brush dynamics set to fade size?

Yes,and the minimum diameter is 0%.

I asked 2 question.. got 1 answer.. and I don't know which of my questions "yes" refers to.

Sorry, what I meant was that it was all yes.I am drawing on a drawing tablet,and pressure sensitivity is okay.There is no problem with the brush settings either.

Well the dynamics (probably pressure) should be set to size and you'll want the Fade off if you are using a tablet. -- I don't know what "CSP" means though.
